# Screen wont dim when I tell it to

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my screen to go dim when I call an activity from a notification. Here is the code I am using:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 0.01f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong here, if so can someone tell me whats going on and why its not working the way its supposed to?!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class NoteMe extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
NotificationManager nm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String title = "Example text";
    String contentText = "Full hello world!";
    String text = "Starting Notification!";

    nm = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, when);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getBaseContext(), title, contentText,
            contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
}
```

Here is the requested code

Comment: please post the code that shows the firing off notification.

Comment: @CodeDroid I put that up for you.

Comment: Ok. you also want to put Logs or debug breakpoints in the MainActivity where the brightness gets called. To see if it reaches that code.  The code you have will adjust the brightness of the screen where it executes only.

Comment: not sure if getBaseContext()  I have posted what should work below.

Comment: try using this instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: Main thing is make sure the Intent is being fired and the Activity is getting started.  So just check that first.

Comment: I'm giving all of this a shot right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is 100% correct.  There are two possibilities the first is the most likely

1) The activity is not getting called off the notification. I believe there is a special way that you fire off from a notification involving pending intents.  I would guess thats the problem.  Just to be sure put some breakpoints in onCreate and onStart to see if it ever gets called. Or just put a log statement near your code to see if it gets called.  I'm guessing it never gets called.

2) The adjustment you are making 0.1f is not visible change.

Please review this and just make sure notifications are being received:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

One difference I see is getContextBase() vs. this

If its not that it looks like maybe MainActivity.class manifest declaration might not be right.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - refreshing the screen after you have set the attribute.

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness =0.01f
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    startActivity(new Intent(this,RefreshScreen.class));
```

So one hack on refreshing the screen is starting dummy activity and than in on create of that dummy activity to call finish(); so the changes of the brightness to take an effect.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted would only dim the screen for your application.  If thats what you want, thats fine.  But if you want to dim the screen on the phone then you need to change the system setting [System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)

```
    // turn on manual control of system screen brightness
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

    final int dimBrightnessValue = 96;  // valid values 0-255
    // change the brightness value
    System.putInt(getContentResolver(), System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, dimBrightnessValue);
```

You would also need to add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Needed for changing screen brightness -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: yes, this is correct if you need it to dim on all screens. Sometimes you need to save the value before doing so in preferences, and than restore however.